# PowerShell code to get pending windows patch count

Tags: windows, powershell

In the past I have used this code to list the count of windows patches:

```
$server = 'ServerName'  
$updatesession = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", $Server))
$updatesearcher = $updatesession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$searchresult = $updatesearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
$PatchCount = $searchresult.Updates.Count       
return $PatchCount
```

However, this code suddenly stopped working for some servers. This could be an artifact of recent windows updates. A similar script (which is also failing) is [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0dbfc125-b855-4058-87ec-930268f03285).

This is the exception I get:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401C
>   At line:5 char:1
>   + $searchresult = $updatesearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Appreciate any help in fixing this code (or if there's a better alternative, that would work too.)

Comment: Please include any errors you are receiving in the question.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest sorry about that. Just included the exception.

Comment: Can you include the full error output, not just the `$exception.Message` bit?

Comment: sure. Let me do that.

Comment: What is the value of `$searchResult.ResultCode`?

Comment: Empty for the server that is raising the exception. However, I ran it on a different server, where the code works, where I got 2 as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `0x8024401C` code means that [the Windows Update service could not be contacted.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-update-error-0x8024401c/130e1025-9207-44aa-a730-950dd5a69bcb)

Comment: This post has bunch of suggestions. I'll try them, and see if it helps. I'll post my findings soon.

Comment: Our server admins, applied the latest wsus updates manually. after this, I don't see the exception anymore. It looks like something to do with the recent windows patches.